# How to test if-condition using \csname within an \ifcase branch

Tags: conditionals

I am trying to test an if-condition, where the name of the condition depends on a macro argument. To do this, I use `\csname ifcondition#1 \endcsname`. This works fine in a simple macro like this:

```
\newif\ifconditionA
\conditionAtrue
\def\test#1{
    \csname ifcondition#1\endcsname
        A: True
    \fi
}
\test{A}
```

However, in my real use case, this test is part of an `\ifcase` branch, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newif\ifconditionA
\conditionAtrue

\def\test#1#2{
\ifcase#2
    Case 0
\or
    %\ifconditionA % This works
    \csname ifcondition#1\endcsname
        Case 1, A: true
    \fi
\fi
}

\test{A}{0}
%\test{A}{1} % This works

\end{document}
```

This fails with the error message `! Extra \fi. \test ...tion#1\endcsname Case 1, A: true \fi \fi`.

If I use the name of the condition directly, without `\csname`, it works fine, and it also works if the branch containing the condition is executed.

What's going on, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The restriction is that the conditions must match, otherwise the skipping of unused branches does not work as expected.

There are several methods. The following exampe uses `\ifx` and compares the constructed conditional with `\iftrue`. Because we have already `\ifx`, the latter is also masked by `\csname`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newif\ifconditionA
\conditionAtrue

\def\test#1#2{%
  \ifcase#2
    Case 0
  \or
    \expandafter
    \ifx\csname ifcondition#1\expandafter\endcsname
        \csname iftrue\endcsname
      Case 1, A: true
    \fi
  \fi
}

\test{A}{0}
\test{A}{1}

\end{document}
```

If you want to have something clearer to use inside macro `\test`, then the magic can be hidden in a macro, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newif\ifconditionA
\conditionAtrue

\newcommand*{\getcondition}[1]{%
  T\expandafter
  \ifx\csname ifcondition#1\endcsname\iftrue
    \expandafter T%
  \else
    \expandafter F%
  \fi
}

\def\test#1#2{%
  \ifcase#2
    Case 0%
  \or
    \if\getcondition{#1}%
      Case 1, #1: true%
    \else
      Case 1, #1: false%
    \fi
  \else
    Other case%
  \fi
}

[\test{A}{0}]
[\test{A}{1}]
[\test{B}{0}]
[\test{B}{1}]
[\test{A}{2}]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Ah, excellent, thank you! It seems like using `\iftrue` directly (without the `\csname`) also works?

Comment: @Jake: No, it will not work, if the `\or` branch is skipped. TeX would see two `\if...` commands and would steal the `\fi` of `\ifcase` to match them.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the fact that `\if` expands tokens until finding unexpandable ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newif\ifconditionA
\conditionAtrue

\def\testcondition#1{\expandafter\TTfi\csname ifcondition#1\endcsname}
\def\TTfi{TT\fi}

\def\test#1#2{%
  \ifcase#2
    Case 0
  \or
    \if\testcondition{#1}%
      Case 1, A: true
    \fi
  \fi
}

\test{A}{0}
\test{A}{1}

\end{document}
```

Let's see how it works. If we are in a skipped over text, that is, the false branch of a conditional or an `\or` branch to be ignored, TeX will match `\if` with the `\fi` (and the possible `\else`) that really corresponds to `\ifconditionA`. If it's in a true branch, then the expansions are

```
\if\testcondition{A}
\if\expandafter\TTfi\csname ifconditionA\endcsname
\if\TTfi\ifconditionA
\if TT\fi\ifconditionA
\ifconditionA
```

so the `\if` is matched to the first `\fi` and the entire group `\if TT\fi` disappears without doing nothing. Then the constructed `\ifconditionA` is matched to its `\else` and `\fi`.